# Android - Let a custom Action Bar fill the width

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar

I have to customize my Action Bar, so I decided to remove the default one and add a view that look like the original AB, but more customized.

By doing this, I noticed that the view I'm using as an AB, doesn't fit in all the activity width.

This is the code of the view:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/action_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/action_bar" />
```

I even tried with the "fill_horizontal" command but doesn't work. I'm using RelativeLayout.

This is how the activity looks like:

[image: Activity]

As you can see the AB view doesn't fit at all.

Answer (score 0):

android:adjustViewBounds="true" set this to false

Comment: If I set it to "false" the view fit in width but some empty space appear to the top and to the bottom, making impossible to attach it to the top of the activity, like this: [Image](http://i.imgur.com/4uRPVSQ.png)